# Need help finding Pokemon Sword logo font

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

Hello I’m trying to find the font used in the logo for Pokemon Sword. I’ve attempted to find the font using likefont, whatisfont and my font to no avail.

All that I’m sure of is that the logo use a uses a commercially available font, that nintendo then made slight modifications to.
Just like the Pokémon Shield logo which uses the font LECO 1976 Alt Diacritics Bold that's been slightly modified by Nintendo

If you have any suggestion for what the font could be please reply to this post
[image]

Comment: Simply googling "pokemon sword font" I found [this](https://www.deviantart.com/mucrush/art/Font-Pack-Sword-796435819). Haven't tried downloading it myself since I don't have a DeviantArt account.

Answer (score 0):

I know many commercial fonts but don't recognize this, it's not something common. Could be custom.

You might though want to try Gabriello and Azurri from Commercial Type, Azurri has the same jagged-extreme slant aesthetic but less extreme but slab-serif, it might be more general-purpose useful, Gabriello is a rounded sans companion design. If you like extreme slant maybe look at Nitro from Monotype/HTF.